# How to optimalize pan and zoom in mapview with multiple lines?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I have mapview activity on witch i add multiple Overlays each with draw line between to geopints. As a source data i have ArrayList object and for every two next locations i dwaw line.

Method witch add overlays

```
public void showPath(ArrayList<Location> log) { 
    int count = 0;
    mapView.getOverlays().clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < (log.size() - 1); i++) {
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (log.get(i).getLatitude() * 1E6),(int) (log.get(i).getLongitude() * 1E6));
        GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint((int) (log.get(i + 1).getLatitude() * 1E6),(int) (log.get(i + 1).getLongitude() * 1E6));
        MapOverlay mapOvlay = new MapOverlay(point, point2); //vytvori overlay s carou mezi body
        mapView.getOverlays().add(mapOvlay);
        count++;
    }

    app.getToast("mumbers of read / display items: " + Integer.toString(orgSize) + " / " + Integer.toString(count));
    Log.d(TAG, "mumbers of read / display items: " + orgSize + " / " + count);

    mapView.setSatellite(true);
    GeoPoint point0 = new GeoPoint((int) (log.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6),(int) (log.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6)); //vycentruje mapu na pocatek zaznamu
    MapController mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setCenter(point0);
    mapView.setEnabled(true);
}
```

This is draw() method in MapOverlay witch extends Overlay

```
@Override
public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
   super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

   Paint paint;
   paint = new Paint();
   paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
   paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
   paint.setStrokeWidth(6);
   paint.setAntiAlias(true);

   Point pt1 = new Point(); 
   Point pt2 = new Point();

   Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();

   projection.toPixels(Gpt1, pt1);
   projection.toPixels(Gpt2, pt2);

   canvas.drawLine(pt1.x, pt1.y, pt2.x, pt2.y, paint);
   return true;
}
```

Problem is when i draw lot of lines about 500, the using map is very slow especially pan and zoom. I tried do draw line into one overlay and add it to map, but te result was the same. Anybody have idea how to optimalize it or another way how to draw line? I don't need to optimalize adding items on the map i need to make moving on the map smoother. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in the other way, pass your array to `MapOverlay` and make the for loop inside the method draw, in this case you will create only one `MapOverlay` instead of 500, and draw 500 lines with one `MapOverlay` and you will get the same result.

If you still didn't understand my answer tell me and I will demonstrate with codes.

Comment: I've try this but it changes nothing. What helps is when in draw() method draw line only when shadows == false. But the improvement was little and pan and zoom is styl slow.